# Como encaixar linhas de uma tabela CSS?

Tags: html, css, table, display

Estou tentando melhorar meus conhecimentos com HTML e CSS e me surgiu uma dúvida/problema.
Estou fazendo uma tabela que começa vazia, e conforme o usuário digita informações em uma `textbox`, ela insere linhas.

O problema que as células não estão se encaixando corretamente dentro da tabela e eu queria manter um tamanho inicial (`height`) pra ela, pois ela deve começar sem linha alguma.

Testei algumas opções usando o `display: block;`, porém com ele não consigo configurar a `%` que cada célula em cada linha ocupa.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```css
#dashboard{
  width:80%;
  border: 2.5px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#table-dashboard{
  width:100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Courier;
}

#table-dashboard tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webroot/css/estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dashboard">
      <table id="table-dashboard">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1.</td>
          <td>Batata</td>
          <td>R$5,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2.</td>
          <td>Cenoura</td>
          <td>R$1,50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3.</td>
          <td>Tomate</td>
          <td>R$3,00</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"O problema que as células não estão se encaixando corretamente dentro da tabela ..."_, não entendi muito bem, poderia explicar melhor? se possível, edite a sua pergunta com uma explicação um pouco mais clara.

Comment: Olá Marlon. É importante você [edit] e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **não deve duplicar (repetir) a pergunta, apenas edite e aguarde o processo de reabertura, ou seja, não delete**, basta editar a pergunta. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.